# css ie/FF completely different from chrome

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

I just finished my portfolio site, which is my first attempt with html5 and it looks great in Chrome. But when I tested it in IE and FF, exept IE9, there are some major differences that all occur in the header. I think this is because the header has a fixed position. I did this because of the menu. I created a one pager and if I didn't set the position on fixed, the menu disappeared when you clicked on a menu item.

A second error is that with IE all the images get a blue border, which doesn't appear on Chrome.

And a third error is the font in the header is also different with IE. I used an @font-face font for it.

My HTML and CSs code validates on W3C.

You can find the website at [www.nathaliedehertogh.be](http://www.nathaliedehertogh.be)

Can someone please help me out with this one.

Comment: I would argue that if it doesn't work as you intended, it's not "finished"

Comment: You're using `<hr />`s and `<br />`s to space out and style your header. I would avoid doing that.

Comment: On FF it looks the same as on IE8 (or IE7 I'm not sure).

Comment: Sounds like you're not using a css normalizer.  You should always normalize css so that all browsers start with the same set of styles.

Comment: I see that you have already added the HTML5 shiv for IE - which is great for fixing a wide swatch of problems.  I think that you will have better luck fixing these problems if you break it out into one problem at a time.  Don't forget to include the appropriate code in the question (so that it's useful to others), tell us what you've tried, and do your research!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add clear:both to #menu, and border:0 to img.

The blue outline is default in some browsers to show that the images are links.

Comment: thank you sooo much!!! I just tested it in FF and IE8 and IE9 and there it's fine now. IE7 still gives me something else, but I'll try to figure it out first.

Answer (score 1):

You need a clear in your header to allow the content to flow as wanted after.

The blue border for IE simply needs a CSS setting:

```
img {
  border: 0;
}
```

As for the font, some fonts don't read correctly in IE.  The error I get is:

@font-face failed OpenType embedding permission check. Permission must be Installable.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a height defined in your div 'kopregel'.. this is causing an issue since you have elements with heights defined inside it.

NOTE: I see it all broken in FF, stuff is being smooshed to the right.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your header is you need the `clear` function in your css.

Here is the new and edited code.

```
#content, hr {
    clear: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

No issue with fixed positions this is just a common issue, hope this helps let me know!

Answer (score -1):

Another major Difference Chrome vs IE check this out
http://technofizzle.blogspot.in/2013/04/chrome-and-ie-display-image-completely.html

Comment: Perhaps add in some highlights (important quotes) from the page instead of pasting the link?